# extract opcodes using radare

Tags: ida, radare2, disassemblers, assembly

When we have many binaries, there is a python base solution for disassemble and extract opcodes from binaries in IDA program.
Is there any or similar solution to disassemble binaries for Radare2?

Comment: use r2pipe? but what output do you expect to get?

Comment: I want disassembled opcodes of binaries. How can I use r2pipe?

Comment: that you can do w/o r2pipe `r2 -c 'pd' -q /bin/ls` or with the address specified  `r2 -c 'pd @ 0x1000012ec' -q /bin/ls`

Comment: Thank you a lot. But I still have a problem, this command does not disassemble the whole file. How can I dis-assemble the whole file?

Comment: 'pd N' and you can specify as N whatever number you want and it will disassemble N instructions

Comment: I suggest you to read the [radare2 book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/), it will teach you the basics.

Comment: Are you sure you want to disassemble "the whole file"?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik how can I determine the N for the whole opcodes?

Comment: I would just use some big number, but I agree with @usr2564301 with the question if you really want to disassemble the whole file.

Comment: I need the whole opcode, so I think It's necessary to disassemble the whole file. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Radare2 uses [capstone](http://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_python.html) for disassembling, and capstone has a python API.

Example from their website:

```
from capstone import *

CODE = b"\x55\x48\x8b\x05\xb8\x13\x00\x00"

md = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64)
for i in md.disasm(CODE, 0x1000):
    print("0x%x:\t%s\t%s" %(i.address, i.mnemonic, i.op_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

**:>radare2 -c "aaa;fs functions;pdf @@ fcn.*;q" x32dbg.exe > foo.txt**

:

```
\>grep -i (fcn) foo.txt
/ (fcn) fcn.004020f7 21
/ (fcn) fcn.00401ff1 266
/ (fcn) fcn.00402580 69
/ (fcn) fcn.004020ee 9
/ (fcn) fcn.004025c5 20
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

a sample disassembled function

```
:\>grep -A 18 -i "(fcn) fcn.004025c5" foo.txt
/ (fcn) fcn.004025c5 20
|   fcn.004025c5 ();
|           ; var int local_10h @ ebp-0x10
|              ; UNKNOWN XREF from 0x004020e5 (sub.KERNEL32.dll_DecodePointer_4e)
|              ; CALL XREF from 0x0040242c (entry0)
|              ; CALL XREF from 0x004020e5 (sub.KERNEL32.dll_DecodePointer_4e)
|              ; CALL XREF from 0x00402647 (fcn.004025fc)
|              ; CALL XREF from 0x004026c1 (fcn.0040266b)
|           0x004025c5      8b4df0         mov ecx, dword [local_10h]
|           0x004025c8      64890d000000.  mov dword fs:[0], ecx
|           0x004025cf      59             pop ecx
|           0x004025d0      5f             pop edi
|           0x004025d1      5f             pop edi
|           0x004025d2      5e             pop esi
|           0x004025d3      5b             pop ebx
|           0x004025d4      8be5           mov esp, ebp
|           0x004025d6      5d             pop ebp
|           0x004025d7      51             push ecx
\           0x004025d8      c3             ret

:\>
```